# SMB error pointing to specific folder

Tags: smb

i did all the instructions right but this always pop up when installing

```
[02/03 17:18:14.012] BINL Err: WIA_RIS_SHARE wrong setup; 127.0.0.1:445 SMB share doesn't point to E:\.Serva\Boot\
```

Can i remap or idk point the smb to my folder?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
[02/03 17:18:14.012] BINL Err: WIA_RIS_SHARE wrong setup; 127.0.0.1:445 SMB share doesn't point to E:\.Serva\Boot\
```

That error says that the `WIA_RIS_SHARE` was not created properly.
It specifically mentions that the share is not pointing to E:.Serva\Boot\ which is
in your installation Serva's repository main directory.

Please remember `WIA_RIS_SHARE`  is only needed if you are planning to net install ancient OSs like Windows 2000, XP, Server 2003, etc.